# Detecting how long a mousedown event lasts then preventing mouseup action if over a certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I am hoping that there is a more elegant solution to this issue. Basically, I have a HTML / Javascript app that will be running on a touch screen kiosk. I am trying to prevent the default click behavior if someone is scrolling through a list of buttons by dragging their finger. At first I tried to preventDefault when it detected a swipe event. But then it occurred to me that it isn't really a swipe event so much as a long mousedown. So I wrote the following code:

```
var downClick;
var startTime;

$(".TPGSW-wrapper").on('mousedown', function () {

    downClick = new Date();
    startTime = downClick.getTime();

});

$(".TPGSW-wrapper").on('mouseup', function () {

    var upClick = new Date();
    var endTime = upClick.getTime();

    if (endTime - startTime < 250) {
        return false;
    } else if (endTime - startTime >= 300) {
        // This is the action that I can't seem to get to work. 
        // I would like it to stop the click event. I also tried mouseup
        this.on('click', function () { preventDefault; });
    }              

});
```

This correctly measures the time of the mousedown, but then I can't seem to stop the click event from firing. Any thoughts or suggestions? I am using jquery and this for a webkit browser only. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might work if you replace `mouseup` with `click` and then just leave `event.preventDefault()` (event being the first argument of the function.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more about whether the user moves their finger more than some threshold distance, rather than an amount of time?

Comment: @Jeff B, yes, that might make sense as well. What I found was that because the div scrolls with it, that the point in relation to the div did not change, but I guess if I looked at the coordinates within the window, that might be a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after some tests i was able to get it to work with the following code:

```
var longpress = false;

$(".TPGSW-wrapper").on('click', function (e) {
    (longpress) ?  e.preventDefault() : alert("clicked");
});

var startTime, endTime;
$(".TPGSW-wrapper").on('mousedown', function () {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
});

$(".TPGSW-wrapper").on('mouseup', function () {
    endTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (endTime - startTime < 250) {
        longpress = false;
        console.log('< 250');
    } else if (endTime - startTime >= 300) {
        longpress = true;
        console.log('>= 300');
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/Makgq/)

the click event will fire if the mouse was held down for less than 250 ms, if it's more than 300 ms it will call `e.preventDefault` and stop the click event.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (endTime - startTime >= 300) {
    $(this).one('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
}
```

Note how "one" not "on" is used. That's so it'll only trigger once, not every time after.

OR per JCOC611's comment, you could remove your mouseup event and use this inplace:

```
$(".TPGSW-wrapper").on('click', function (e) {
    var upClick = new Date();
    var endTime = upClick.getTime();

    if (endTime - startTime >= 300) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }              
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually didn't work either, though it does clean up what I had. I think because the action is bound to the click event but I need to measure the time of the mouseup. So in the end, I either can measure the mouseup, or prevent the click event, but I cant do both.